# XCode - Data-Driven testing?

Tags: xcode, ios-ui-automation, xcode-instruments

I am new to XCode Instruments automation. I am very curious of one thing & i could not find figure out any online help on this. How to do data-driven automation?  ie, I have a script to register an user with first name, last name and address details in an application. Like that I need to register 500 users. I have my data in CSV file. Is there any way to get the data from CSV / XML / JSON / Any other approach you suggest to deal with the scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Is "Register 500 Users at once" really a test case or is test setup? If it is a test case, it looks like that you want to test your backend. Doing this by using ui automation is not a good idea, because it it is too slow (hard to stress your backend with that) and too complex. If you want to (stress) test your backend do server testing with tools like JMeter. If it is test setup you can call any shell command from your automation script. For example you could write a script or program which takes your file containing your users and iterate over it and create calls to your backend for every entry. Of course this will only work when using the simulator to execute your test case. This is the API you need: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIAutomation/Reference/UIAHostClassReference/UIAHost/UIAHost.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011044

Answer (score 0):

One way is to convert your data into a json format which can be imported into your script. Using that you can easily loop through the json data and repeat the step required for the registering the user.